# module 'coco' has no attribute 'cocoConfig'

Tags: python

```
import coco
# from samples.coco import coco
config = coco.cocoConfig()



COCO_DIR = "/Users/anusha/Desktop/MLANusha/coco/val2017"
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 import coco
2 # from samples.coco import coco
----> 3 config = coco.cocoConfig()
4 COCO_DIR = "/Users/anusha/Desktop/MLANusha/coco/val2017"

AttributeError: module 'coco' has no attribute 'cocoConfig'

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
(Copied from github: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1595)

Install Visual studio build tools from this link
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Then clone the cocoapi repository from github
git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git

After cloning, go to the PythonAPI sub-directory in the same folder and run,
python setup.py install

If all these steps went well then you are good to go.

Or simply you can try:
!pip install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"

And then try to import
from pycocotools.coco import COCO